# Is there a theological distinction between being a "sinner" and being"wicked?"

Tags: sin, good-and-evil

Does either scripture or historical theology make a distinction between being a sinner (which all humans are) and being wicked or evil?

Comment: This depends on whom you ask. Which perspective are you seeking?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a theological distinction between being a “sinner” and being “wicked?”**

> James 5:20  Let him know, that he which converteth the sinner from the
>   error of his way shall save a soul from death, and shall hide a
>   multitude of sins.
>
> 1Corinthians 5:13  But them that are without God judgeth. Therefore
>   put away from among yourselves that wicked person.

sinner = hamartōlos = one who misses the mark

wicked = ponēros = hurtful, evil, morally culpable, vicious, malicious, derelict

It looks like one could make the case that a sinner gets it wrong and someone wicked is wrong. The distinction being the extent to which the inner character has been corrupted. We should be thankful that the love of Jesus transcends even the lowest state to which we can sink.